# How can i test an application for 1000 iPad,because i have only 1 ipad & i want to perform the load testing.for server side data

Tags: ios-simulator, ipad-2, ipad

How can i test an application for 1000 iPad,because i have only 1 ipad & i want to perform the load testing.for server side data and want to see the response time when i hit the button from the UI (ipad).